HTML images showing up as [obj] (with a dotted box) when using an <img> tag for an email's html body
Currently, I am trying to open an email draft using react-native-mail to send some information and a file for an app I am building. Currently I am including steps on how to use the file correctly but I want to add some pictures that I am already using through my app in the draft to make it easier for the user.
This is how I am sending the email currently:
Mailer.mail({
    subject: subject,
    recipients: [''],
    body: this.getEmailHTML(),
    isHTML: true,
    attachments: [
            {
            path: filePath,
            type: 'wav',
            name: filename
                }
            ]}

Currently, the getEmailDraft() function is only doing this:

getEmailHTML() {
      return `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">                  
        </head>
        <body>
    
               <img src="./assets/Lassie.png">
                    
            </body>
        </html>`

    }



All I get for an output is this (see the red arrow):
email output
I believe the image should just appear here but for some reason it isn't. The image is just a picture of a dog that I Downloaded off the internet and is stored in my assets directory.

Could be an encoding issue. I have this one which is a little bit lengthier than yours <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
